# What's the difference between HashSet and Set?

Tags: java, interface, set

Saw the code snippet like

```
Set<Record> instances = new HashSet<Record>();
```

I am wondering if Hashset is a special kind of set. Any difference between them?

Comment: You might want to check out the concept of [interfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

A `Set` represents a generic "set of values". A `TreeSet` is a set where the elements are sorted (and thus ordered), a `HashSet` is a set where the elements are *not* sorted or ordered.

A `HashSet` is typically a lot faster than a `TreeSet`.

A `TreeSet` is typically implemented as a red-black tree (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree - I've not validated the actual implementation of sun/oracle's `TreeSet`), whereas a `HashSet` uses `Object.hashCode()` to create an index in an array. Access time for a red-black tree is `O(log(n))` whereas access time for a `HashSet` ranges from constant-time to the worst case (every item has the same hashCode) where you can have a linear search time `O(n)`.

Comment: Additionally, there are these general-purpose-implementations: LinkedHashSet (a variant of HashSet which preserves some order for the Iterator), ConcurrentSkipListSet (a threadsave SortedSet implementation), CopyOnWriteArraySet (a thread-safe variant optimized for "lots of reads, very seldom writes"), EnumSet (which works only on enum types for the elements, but then is even faster than HashSet).

Comment: @Erik: I request to edit your answer. TreeSet is sorted not ordered. HashSet = Unordered, TreeSet = sorted, LinkedHashSet = ordered. Please modify your answer accordingly

Comment: Hashset can be slower if the implementation of hashCode is bad (e.g. always return the same hashcode)

Answer (score 44):

The [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is an implementation of a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 20):

The question has been answered, but I haven't seen the answer to why the code mentions both types in the same code.

Typically, you want to code against interfaces which in this case is Set. Why? Because if you reference your object through interfaces always (except the new HashSet()) then it is trivial to change the implementation of the object later if you find it would be better to do so because you've only mentioned it once in your code base (where you did new HashSet()).

Answer (score 12):

Set is the general interface to a set-like collection, while HashSet is a specific implementation of the Set interface (which uses hash codes, hence the name).

Answer (score 5):

Set is a parent interface of all set classes like TreeSet, LinkedHashSet etc.

HashSet is a class implementing Set interface.

Answer (score 1):

HashSet is a class derived from Set interface. As a derived class of Set, the HashSet attains the properties of Set. Important and the most frequently used derived classes of Set are HashSet and TreeSet.

Answer (score -1):

**

- Set:

**
It is an interface which is a subtype of Collection interface, just like LIST and QUEUE.

Set has below 3 subclasses, it is used to store multiple objects without duplicates.

1. HashSet
2. LinkedHashSet
3. TreeSet(which implements SortedSet interface)

**

- HashSet:

**

Can use one NULL value(as Duplicate is not allowed), data is stored randomly as it does not maintain sequence.