# Difference between Set and HashSet in Java

Tags: java

What is the difference between `Set` and `Hash Set` in java? 
When to use either of these?

Comment: do you know the difference between interfaces and classes?

Comment: Set is interface and HashSet is class which implements Set

Comment: You use a `Set` if you want to create your own `Set`, because it´s an `interface`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139724/whats-the-difference-between-hashset-and-set

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139724/whats-the-difference-between-hashset-and-set

Answer (score 5):

`Set` is an interface, `HashSet` - implementation of interface. It is recommended to use interface instead of implementation when you declaring variables.

If go further into details, an interface in Java is a set of methods, and if some class wants to implement this interface, it must implement all of its methods.

The `Set` interface represents a set of some objects, non-ordered, without random-element access. `HashSet` - implementation of the `Set` interface, based on the `.hashCode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `HashSet` is an implementation of a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` represents a generic "set of values". A `TreeSe`t is a set where the elements are sorted (and thus ordered), a `HashSet` is a set where the elements are not sorted or ordered.

A `HashSet` is typically a lot faster than a `TreeSet`.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139724/whats-the-difference-between-hashset-and-set).