# Improving HashSet Design in Python

Tags: python, hashset

learning here!

I've managed to pull together this solution for a question on Leetcode!
Heres the stats for this solution:
Runtime: 1236 ms, faster than 17.28% of Python3 online submissions for Design HashSet
Memory Usage: 18.7 MB, less than 83.53% of Python3 online submissions for Design HashSet.

Now - I wish that Leetcode would show an Ideal or Best practice solution just so I can compare and learn with mine! But they don't!

So, It would be appreciated if any of you can here! (Critique and show your Best practice solution)

[image: Task Description]

**My Solution**

````
class MyHashSet:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.TheSet = []
        

    def add(self, key: int) -> None:
        if self.contains(key):
            pass
        else:
            if key >= 0 and key <= 10**6:
                self.TheSet.append(key)
            else:
                pass

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        if self.contains(key):
            self.TheSet.remove(key)
        else:
            pass

    def contains(self, key: int) -> bool:
        if key in self.TheSet:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        


# Your MyHashSet object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = MyHashSet()
# obj.add(key)
# obj.remove(key)
# param_3 = obj.contains(key)```
````

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to the challenge? Your code does not use Hashes as the name would suggest. Perhaps, that could improve your solution.

Comment: Please edit the images in your question so they are __text__ so code is a [mre] including data __as text__

Comment: "Here is my code, it works but maybe it can be improved, please critique" isn't a question suitable for Stack Overflow - this should be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Because you aren't actually implementing a hash set... You are just using a list... The whole point of hash sets are hat they are better performing than lists for checking membership

Answer (score 1):

I found the challenge and played a little bit. I guess the problem is that you do not use the underlying concept of a HashSet, which would be explained in the challenge you tried on LeetCode. Here is also a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558754/define-what-is-a-hashset) where they explained what a HashMap does. Would check it out!

I also made a solution for you based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409214/7947994). It has a runtime of better than 80% and memory usage better than 90%. Clearly, this can be further improved, but I think it contains the essential concepts.

```
class MyHashSet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = [None] * 1_000
        
    def hash(self, x):
        return x % (2 ** 61 - 1)
    
    def add(self, key:int) -> None:
        key_hash = self.hash(key) % 1_000
        bucket = self.contents[key_hash]
        
        if bucket is None:
            self.contents[key_hash] = [key]
        elif key not in bucket:
            bucket.append(key)
        return None

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        key_hash = self.hash(key) % 1_000
        bucket = self.contents[key_hash]
        
        if bucket is not None:
            if key in bucket:
                bucket.remove(key)
        else:
            pass
        
    def contains(self, key: int) -> bool:
        key_hash = self.hash(key) % 1_000
        bucket = self.contents[key_hash]
        
        if bucket is not None:
            if key in bucket:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: There is no need to keep None initially; just have the list be empty.